# Конвертация универсального типа <T> в Nullable<T>?

Tags: c#

**Как из метода `GetValue()` возвратить значение типа `Nullable`** .

При этом я хотел бы обеспечить возможность передавать в качестве универсального типа `<T>` как типы значений, так и ссылочные типы.

Упрощенный пример, отражающий суть проблемы:

```
class DataStructure <T>
{
   private T Value { get; set; }

   Nullable<T> GetValue()
   {
       // В данном методе нужно из не Nullable Т-типа получить Nullable<T>
       // Приведенный ниже способ VisualStudio подчеркивает как ошибку.
       return this.Value as T?;
   }
}
```

использование метода `Convert.ChangeType()` задачу также решить не помогло:

```
class DataStructure <T>
{
   private T Value { get; set; }

   Nullable<T> GetValue()
   {           
       // Приведенный ниже способ VisualStudio подчеркивает как ошибку.
       return (T?)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T?));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` имеет смысл только для структур. Вам нужно добавить ограничение на `T`:

```
class DataStructure<T> where T: struct
```

В этом случае преобразование между `T?` и `T` станет тривиально, и компилятор сам сможет его выполнить:

```
Nullable<T> GetValue()
{
    return Value;
}
```

---

А использовать `Nullable<T>` для ссылочных типов `T` невозможно.

Comment: Проверил, перечитал документацию, да работает. Но, не совсем подходит в моем случае. Судя по всему я плохо сформулировал проблему. Я хотел бы обеспечить возможность передавать в качестве универсального типа <T> как типы значений, так и ссылочные типы. Данное решение ставит ограничение в использовании типа T, запрещая передавать в качестве значения ссылочные типы. Хотелось бы избежать данного ограничения в идеале.

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko: То, чего вы хотите, невозможно. `Nullable<T>` не бывает со ссылочными типами. Типа `Nullable<string>`, например, быть не может. Вы не обойдётесь без ограничения.

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko: Ограничение на `T` вводится уже тем, что вы _используете_ `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko: Если такое уж сильное желание оборачивать и ссылки в Nullable<T>, создайте свой класс с аналогичным функционалом, только без ограничения на <T>. И везде в проекте используйте эту самоделку вместо Nullable<T>

Comment: @velial: Кстати, прекрасная идея.